# Python: Making a method utilizing a while loop for a user's input?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Practicing coding by trying to make a Roman Numerals Converter. I'm trying to make a method that contains a while loop that calls for the user's input. I am confused as how to go about doing so.

Here is the created class with **init** method.

```
class RomanNumeral: 
    """A class to represent our roman numerals or integers."""
    def __init__(self, user_input): 
        """Initializes the user's input, a counter, and standard values for each roman numeral."""
        self.input = user_input
        self.rom_dict = {u'M\u0305': 1000000, u'C\u0305M\u0305': 900000, u'D\u0305': 500000, \
                    u'C\u0305D\u0305': 400000, u'C\u0305': 100000, u'X\u0305C\u0305': 90000, \
                    u'L\u0305': 50000, u'X\u0305L\u0305': 40000, u'X\u0305': 10000, \
                    u'I\u0305X\u0305': 9000, u'V\u0305': 5000, u'I\u0305V\u0305': 4000, 'M': 1000, \
                    'CM': 900, 'D': 500, 'CD': 400, 'C': 100, 'XC': 90, 'L': 50, 'XL': 40, 'X': 10, \
                    'IX': 9, 'V': 5, 'IV': 4, 'I': 1}
```

Rest of the code for reference.

```
    def rom_or_int(self):
                """Checks if user input is a roman numeral, integer, or not."""
                # Checks if user input is a integer
                if self.input.isdigit():
                    number = int(self.input)
                    print("The equivalent Roman Numeral is: " + self.int_to_rom(number) + ".\n")
                # Checks if user input is a roman numeral, if so run method 
                elif self.isroman():
                    self.rom_to_int()
                # If not, print this statement
                else:
                    print("Entry is neither in roman numerals or an integer.\n")

        def isroman(self):
            """Checks if user input is a roman numeral."""
            for i in self.input:
                if i not in self.rom_dict.keys():
                    return False
            return True

        def int_to_rom(self, number):
            """Takes the user input of integer and converts it to Roman Numerals."""
            # Create a list of tuples for the standard values of the roman numerals
            roman_numeral = "" # empty string to create roman numeral

            for k,v in self.rom_dict.items():
                if number - v >= 0: # finds the greatest integer value that can be subtracted from input
                    x = number // v # x is the number of times the current roman numeral appears
                    number -= x*v # subtract the input from the roman numeral to be added to the string
                    roman_numeral += x * k # the string is now x amount of the roman numeral
            return roman_numeral

        def rom_to_int(self): # next() function? LXD and DXL give wrong answers.
            """Takes in user_input in roman numerals and return the equivalent integer."""
            rom_dict = {'M': 1000, 'D': 500, 'C': 100, 'L': 50, 'X': 10, 'V': 5, 'I': 1}

            integer = 0 # counter

            # Iterates the user's input
            for i in range(len(self.input)):
                roman_value = rom_dict[self.input[i]] # checks the integer value of the current iteration

                # if the subceding roman numeral is of greater value, subtract
                if i+1 < len(self.input) and roman_value < rom_dict[self.input[i+1]]:
                    integer -= roman_value
                else: # if not add
                    integer += roman_value

            # checks to see if this is a valid Roman Numeral by comparing to the output of the int_to_rom method
            check_value = self.int_to_rom(integer)
            if self.input == check_value:
                print("The equivalent integer value is: " + str(integer) + ".\n")
                return integer
            else:
                print("This is not a proper roman numeral.\n")
```

Currently, I'm using this way of asking for the user's input

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("Press 'Enter' without an input to exit program.")
        user_input = (input("Enter a Roman Numeral or integer to convert: "))
        if user_input == "":
            exit()
        x = RomanNumeral(user_input)
        x.rom_or_int()
```

I was thinking about doing this:

```
def user_input(self):

    while True:
            print("Press 'Enter' without an input to exit program.")
            user_input = (input("Enter a Roman Numeral or integer to convert: "))
            if user_input == "":
                exit()
            x = RomanNumeral(user_input)
            x.rom_or_int()
```

But, I don't know how to go about instantiating the class to utilize the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

Two notes:

- You named the a function *and* a variable the same name, `user_input` this can cause unforeseen errors
- Replaced `exit()` with `return` since we are running in a function now

```py
def user_input(self):

    while True:
            print("Press 'Enter' without an input to exit program.")
            ui = (input("Enter a Roman Numeral or integer to convert: "))
            if ui == "":
                return  # return > exit(), because this is in a function
            x = RomanNumeral(ui)
            x.rom_or_int()
            # will continue to loop, until user enters a null string as input
```

Keep in mind, this functoin will *only* exit if the user enters a null string

Comment: Awesome, but dumb question: I just am confused as to how to call the function in the name/main block. The function already instantiates the function. I can't simply use user_input().

Comment: Edit: Nevermind. I figured it out. Turn it into a class method. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad we could get it figured out!